# Help on Restructure URLs (Move Parts of URL) with Mod-Rewrite

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a multi-language WordPress website where the URL has the following URL structure:

http://www.domain.com/yyyy/mm/dd/abcdefg/xx-yy/

where xx-yy is the language code.

I intend to make the URL as below:

http://www.domain.com/xx-yy/yyyy/mm/dd/abcdefg/

Where the language code in URL has been moved to the front.

Anybody has any idea what mod-rewrite code which i can used in .htaccess to automatically redirect from the old URL to new URL?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule to make that work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)\/(.+)\/(.*)\/$ /$5/$1/$2/$3/$4/
```

This will redirect: `http://www.domain.com/2011/04/07/abcdefg/xx-yy/` to `http://www.domain.com/xx-yy/2011/04/07/abcdefg/`

Comment: Hi thanks. Is there any any mod-rewrite rules that can incorporate the following variants: Firstly, the some language codes can be just xx instead of xx-yy. Secondly, I would like to explicitly handle some language code to tidy it up. For example, for en I would like it to be en-US when redirected to the front part of URL. Is it possible to handle this in .htaccess?  Thanks a lot.